# Android BLE API: Autoconnect does not work for every device?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean, peripherals, gatt

I have two peripheral devices, say device1 & device2 and one Android device for central role. Android can connect to both by **BluetoothDevice**.*connectGatt*() method with **autoConnect**  = *false*.

Problem is - While **autoConnect** functionalities work well for device1, device2 even does not connect for once with **autoConnect** = *true*.

**onConnectionStateChange** callback is not called in either side (android & device2). 
Advertisement and scan-response packets been customized in device2, is that causing the problem? Though we know that, settings for autonomous connection is to be provided entirely at central side, peripheral side has nothing to do with it, change in peripheral device also changing auto-connect behavior at central side.

any insight? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069507/solved-gatt-callback-fails-to-register
this link might answer your problem