# Android bluetooth scan, connection performance vary from phone type

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm implementing a bluetooth client to connect to a bluetooth server module.

It worked good in my LG G3(M) but I figured out that it doesn't work as expected on Samsung devices. The Galaxy S7(M), despite using the same version of android, fails to scan devices, and the connection is very unstable.

For now, I think the performance of the bluetooth code depends hardly on the maker or the hardware I'm testing on. Am I clear about this? If not, how can I make the performance uniform in all devices?

Comment: Some code, some details will surely allow us to help.

Comment: Bluetooth is highly device/chip dependent. It does not deliver the same results/performance across devices

Comment: So, does this mean that there is hardly no device independent code to use?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run on the UIThread using a Runnable and a Handler.

```
Runnable connectSamsung = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false,
                                            mGattCallback);
    }
};

mHandler.post(connectSamsung);
```

See this question:

[GATT callback fails to register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069507/gatt-callback-fails-to-register)