# How to solve the error onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=7 in BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an Android application which uses **Bluetooth Low Energy** (BLE) to connect with my phone. The application worked well in almost all phones such as Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0.1), Galaxy S6 (Android 6.0). However, it has a critical issue in Galaxy Note 3 (Android 5.0.1).

When I call the `connect()` function, and then call the `readCharacteristic()`, it returns the error:

> onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=7

The error happens after I call the `connect` function for about 2 seconds.   I look up some solution, such as making a delay before calling `readCharacteristic()`, but it cannot solve.

Could you have any way to solve my issue?

Thank all.

This is my code:

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
   @Override
   public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            
     if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {               
        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();      
     } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {}
     }

     @Override
     public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
       if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            readCharacteristic();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

       } else {
           Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
       }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {           
     }

     @Override
     public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {            
     }
 };

 public void readCharacteristic() {
   /*check if the service is available on the device*/
   BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("00001c00-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00123"));
   /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
   BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00001233-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5"));
   mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(mReadCharacteristic, true);
   BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = mReadCharacteristic.getDescriptor(
                UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
   descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
   mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
 }
```

This is my full service function file to connect BLE

```
public class ConnectionService extends Service{
    private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
    public String mDeviceAddress="0A:1B:6C:22:11:3D";
    private ServiceMonitor serviceMonitor = ServiceMonitor.getInstance();
    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {           
            mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
            if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            }
            mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBluetoothLeService = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();        
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(mGattUpdateReceiver!=null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
        }
        if(mServiceConnection!=null) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {      
        //If some device is connecting to phone, let disconnect 
        if(mConnected==true) {
            mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();           
        } 
        //If bluetooth is enable    
        if (BleUtils.getBluetoothAdapter(getApplicationContext()).enable()) {
            Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
            bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
            //Try to reconnect if the connect is not successful
            if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
                new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
                    public void onFinish() {
                        final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
                    }
                }.start();
            }            
        }
        return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Are you making call to connect() method from UI Thread or worker thread?

Comment: I call connect function in a service. It worked well for almost device, except some device, such as Note 3

Comment: Can you post code of service class if possible.

Comment: Yes. Wait me. I will make it now

Comment: @PravinD: Let see my update. The class `BluetoothLeService.java` got from google sample code

Comment: What is BluetoothLeService? Also check this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069507/gatt-callback-fails-to-register/20507449#20507449

Comment: BluetoothLeService is from google sample. If you used BLE before, you will know what is this

Comment: Yes I used BLE but generally I give naming conventions as per my requirement not just as it is provided by some other parties.

Comment: Have you checked with the link I provided?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt/BluetoothLeService.java

Comment: Sorry. I copy wrong. Second link is correct one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130098/discussion-between-pravin-d-and-user8430).

Comment: Are you resolved this issue??

Comment: Sorry. I did not receive the device yet. I will test it on monday or thursday

Comment: Ok...Let me know if solution in provided link works or not.

Comment: Hi currently i am facing this problem gatt disconnected with 22 https://stackoverflow.com/q/47596419/4111151

Comment: @prasanthMurugan Can you refer answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434555/onservicesdiscovered-never-called-while-connecting-to-gatt-server/48636715#48636715 may help

Answer (score 1):

There are different parameters for `connectGatt()` method, it differs from API version. This is kotlin code. I don't see your connect method anywhere but i know you have to call connectGatt() somewhere.

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M -> bluetoothDevice?.connectGatt(applicationContext, true, mGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)

else -> bluetoothDevice?.connectGatt(applicationContext, false, mGattCallback)
```