# register with gatt stack failed Error BLE android Samsung

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I got this "register with GATT stack failed" error on Samsung S7 marshmallow. The scenario is that I am working with 21 BLE peripherals (nrf52). I scan available devices and then connect => write data => disconnect devices one by one. After trying a few times, it give me this error. If I exist the application , it is recover back. Please help!

Already Try : Write on main UI thread for all connectGatt, disconnectGatt method. I know the question is duplicate to
[GATT callback fails to register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069507/gatt-callback-fails-to-register) on stackoverflow. But it is not working for me.

This is code

```
public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
         mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt( this,false, mGattCallback);


        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }

 public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
            }
        });
    }

 public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        Log.w(TAG, "mBluetoothGatt closed");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = null;
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }
```

In my Main Activity, I used broadcast receiver

```
 public final BroadcastReceiver myUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              /*
    Broadcast receiver will listen the listener respond from registered service UartService.class
     */
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothConstants.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                Log.d("Connected Device ", intent.getStringExtra(action) + "is connected ");

                //Connection made, here you can make a decision: do you want to initiate service discovery.
                // P.S. If you are working with multiple devices,
                // make sure that you start the service discovery
                // after all desired connections are made
                // }
            }
            if (BluetoothConstants.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                if (filterQueue.size() != 0) {
                    mDevice = filterQueue.poll();
                    progressDlg.setMessage("Start Initiating to " + mDevice.getName());
                    progressDlg.show();
                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mService.connect(mDevice.getAddress(), getApplicationContext());
                            scanLeDevice(false);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    progressDlg.cancel();
                    connectionQueue.clear();
                }              
            }

            /* if uart servcie is discovered, will preload based on the appointement name,
            * Setting value will get from global variable.*/

            if (BluetoothConstants.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                mService.enableTXNotification();
                mDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(intent.getStringExtra(action));


                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mService.writeRXCharacteristic(value);
                        }
                    });
                    Log.d("Sent Value", "Sent Value");

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            // Action Data Available is thel listener which will be trigger when data is successfully send.
            if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE)) {

                        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mService.disconnect();
                            }
                        });


                        // mService.disconnect();
                        if (filterQueue.size() == 0) {
                            progressDlg.cancel();
                            connectionQueue.clear();
                        }
                        if (txValue[0] == 0) {
                        } else {
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }


                if (action.equals(UartService.DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART)) {
                    mService.disconnect();
                    if (connectionQueue != null) {
                        connectionQueue.poll();
                    } else {
                        progressDlg.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };


 private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
   /* Connect to device found */
            Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));

            BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
            byte[] manufacturerData = BleUtils.getManufacturerAdvertisementData(result.getScanRecord().getBytes());

            Log.e(TAG, Arrays.toString(manufacturerData));
            if (device != null) {
                if (result.getRssi() > -92 && device != null && device.getName() != null) {
                    {
                        if (device.getName().contains("-")) {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(new BleDevice(device, result.getRssi(), manufacturerData));
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            onDeviceFound(device);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mLeDeviceListAdapter != null) {
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // adapter.resetColor(0);
                //writeLine("No Device Detected");
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
   /* Process a batch scan results */
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("Scan Item: ", sr.toString());
            }
        }
    };
```

The following is my logcat :

```
05-14 17:45:05.254 5018-5200/? E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler: com.example.jinghu.smartmagazine, msg: MESSAGE_STOP_SCAN
05-14 17:45:05.254 5018-5182/? E/BtGatt.ScanManager: default value of curScanSetting 0 is choosen
05-14 17:45:08.064 5018-5115/? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: aclStateChangeCallback: State:Connected to Device:F5:E8:84:5E:09:XX, linktype is 2
05-14 17:45:08.094 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: already has a pending command!!
05-14 17:45:08.804 5018-5115/? E/bt_btif_gatt: bta_to_btif_uuid: Unknown UUID length 63201!
05-14 17:45:09.434 24160-24160/com.example.jinghu.myapp E/UartService: mBluetoothGatt nullandroid.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@4ed0d4f
05-14 17:45:09.604 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Connection doesnt exist. Drop indication!
05-14 17:45:10.254 5018-5352/? E/bt_btm: btm_ble_get_search_if search_if=4
05-14 17:45:10.254 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_mark_bg_conn unable to find the bg connection mask for: f5:e8:84:5e:09:a6
05-14 17:45:10.294 5018-5352/? E/bt_btm: btm_sec_disconnected :: clear unused flags. p_dev_rec->sm4 : 0
05-14 17:45:10.304 5018-5115/? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: aclStateChangeCallback: State:DisConnected to Device:F5:E8:84:5E:09:XX
05-14 17:45:10.304 3981-4166/? E/BluetoothEventManager: ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
05-14 17:45:10.324 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.324 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.324 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.344 5018-5018/? E/BluetoothPbapService: Device  F5:E8:84:5E:09:A6 not waiting for authorization..Skipping cancel dialog...
05-14 17:45:10.424 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.424 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.424 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.494 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.494 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.494 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.584 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.584 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.584 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.694 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.694 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.694 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:10.754 24160-24160/com.example.jinghu.myApp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-14 17:45:12.054 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:12.054 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:12.054 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
05-14 17:45:12.064 5018-5352/? E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_deregister Deregister Failedm unknown client cif
05-14 17:45:33.104 3528-4160/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1813 [05-14 17:45:33.111]
05-14 17:46:03.104 3528-4160/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1814 [05-14 17:46:03.113]
05-14 17:46:33.104 3528-4160/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1815 [05-14 17:46:33.115]
```

Comment: first could you please send the code that make this error and say which line cause it and second you shouldn't do this in main thread, use intentservice or asynctask instead.

Comment: @Mehran Zamani I've edited my question

Comment: where do you call `public boolean connect(final String address)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call close() on the BluetoothGatt object when you're done with it. Otherwise you will eventually run out of available BluetoothGatt objects.

Comment: but If I call close(), The ble will not connect to another ble device. My logic is connect => write data => disconnect => connect another device... repeating

Comment: Android has a very limited maximum number of available BluetoothGatt objects. Therefore you must close each BluetoothGatt object after you have disconnected the device.

Comment: Like u said, I put BluetoothGatt object close function after every connection, this error is solved. Thanks.